# Text View insert an image in Placeholder Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitextfield

How could I insert an image in my placeholder "(Right Here)Enter optional text here..."?

```
@IBOutlet var textView : UITextView!
var placeholderLabel : UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    textView.delegate = self
    placeholderLabel = UILabel()
    placeholderLabel.text = "Enter optional text here..."
    placeholderLabel.font = UIFont.italicSystemFontOfSize(textView.font.pointSize)
    placeholderLabel.sizeToFit()
    textView.addSubview(placeholderLabel)
    placeholderLabel.frame.origin = CGPointMake(5, textView.font.pointSize / 2)
    placeholderLabel.textColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.3)
    placeholderLabel.hidden = countElements(textView.text) != 0
}

func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    placeholderLabel.hidden = countElements(textView.text) != 0
}
```

Comment: Question 1: Is this UITextView going to go on to multiple lines? Or simply be a single line?  // Question 2: Is there a reason you are using a UILabel for a placeholder? Because UITextView has an attribute of placeholder you could use for this purpose! Less complicated.

Comment: no on one single line

Comment: No on single lines, meaning... this will be multiple lines?

Comment: I just want to add an image inside the "Enter optional text here..." and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is possible with [`leftView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/leftView) on the field.  Set yourself as the field's delegate and in 
`textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` set  a `UIImageView` as the `leftView` when the new text is empty and clear it when the new text's length is greater than 0.

To get the new text use `var newText:NSString = self.projectSearchTxtFld.text.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)`.